# URLrewriteFilter tuckey redirect

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to use `UrlRewriteFilter` to do a redirect. As we are moving servers and infrastructure all the time to develop our in house cloud solutions we plan to use a lot of this.

My problem is I have a URL like

> https:// google.com/web-app/servlet?**request-parameters&values**

I need to redirect all the `URL`s which has a value for a particular parameter to a different server.

so a URL like :

> https:// google.com/administrator/servlet/ej.processOrder?sec=100&geo=appointment&cus=dubai

If the parameters contain `cus=dubai`, I need to redirect it to

> https://hotmail.com/servlet/ej.processOrder?sec=100&geo=appointment&cus=dubai

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```xml
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
    <rule match-type="wildcard">
        <name>Redirect requests to cases</name>
        <description></description>
        <from>/administrator/servlet/**?**</from>
        <to type="redirect" last="true">http://hotmail.com:8080/servlet/$1?&amp;cus=dubai&amp;$2&amp;$3&amp</to>
    </rule> 
</urlrewrite>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make use of the `query-string` and make sure it matches a particular condition.

From what I can see you would want something like this :

```xml
<condition name="query-string" operator="equal">*cus=dubai*</condition>
```

You will need a rule for each different parameter.  One full rule would look like this :

```xml
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">

    <rule match-type="wildcard">
        <name>Cus = dubai</name>
        <from>/administrator/servlet/*</from>
        <condition name="query-string" operator="equal">*cus=dubai*</condition>
        <to type="redirect" last="true">https://hotmail.com/servlet/ej.processOrder?sec=100&geo=appointment&cus=dubai</to>
    </rule> 

    <!-- other rules go here -->

</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition shall be "type" instead of "name", as:

```
<condition type="query-string" operator="equal">*cus=dubai*</condition>
```

Comment: Your answer does not explain anything.  And it looks very similar to bloopers answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and for a situation that I imagine occurs often it is not very well documented in the [manual](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/index.html) in my opinion.

The following worked for me -

```
<rule>
<condition type="query-string">foo=123&amp;bar=456</condition>
<from>/index.jsp</from>
<to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://somehwere-else.com/blah/blah/</to>
</rule>
```

So this should work for you -

```
<rule>
<name>Redirect requests to cases</name>
<condition type="query-string">sec=100&amp;geo=appointment&amp;cus=dubai</condition>
<from>/administrator/servlet</from>
<to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://hotmail.com:8080/servlet/sec=100&amp;geo=appointment&amp;cus=dubai</to>
</rule>
```